# Ansible and crontabs

Tags: ansible

I am very newbie with ansible. I have been writing some playbooks and well, its awesome. However I am stuck with a very simple admin task that every admin has to learn how to manage. Scenario is very common, lot of servers: ubuntu, centos, servers of differents customers, etc

My question is how I must organize my ansible structure to manage crontabs of the different servers?

I have wrote playbooks which can be applied to the most of the servers with some admin tasks: apt-get udpate, install ntp servers and synchronize, but I don't find the right way to make a ansible structure of files (main.yml, host_vars, files,templates,roles,etc) to manage every single cron of every server.

Do you have any example or any advice?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know Im not an expert but If some ansible newbie has the same problem as me maybe this can help.

As I wrote few days ago, you are learning ansible, you have a lot of servers, you even can install nginx, php-fpm, mysql, etc in a very new ubuntu/centos box in a few minutes. What I am saying? Not one but servers at the same time, the dream. But oh oh now you have to install different cron tasks in lemp server 1 and lemp server 2.

Then, you have to play with ansible variables. When you are newbie in the ansible world the variables can be a little tricky.

I am not saying this is the better approach but, at least, you don't have to maintain individual cron files for every single server.

First, I check the ansible_hostname of lemp server 1

```
$ ansible lempserver1 -m setup|grep host
"ansible_hostname": "ns227962",
```

as you see, the hostname returned by ansible is ns227962. Then I have a ansible structure like:

-- main.yml
 |_ roles
  |_cron
   |_tasks
    |_main.yml

in the main of cron role I have

```
---
- name: add line to crontab's root - backup
  cron: name="backup openvz vps" hour="5" minute="1" weekday="7"  job="/root/scripts/openvz_backup_vps > /dev/null"
  when: "ansible_hostname == 'ns227962'"
```

Notice that is the when statement and ansible_hostname will do the trick.

Then I apply the main.yml and that's all

```
TASK: [cron | add line to crontab's root - backup] ***********
skipping: [lempserver2]
changed: [lempserver1]
```

It worked! :)

In other situations when you have the same file config but there are parts that are slightly different using templates will be helpful.

Now for me its ok, now I can centralize the manage of the crons servers only with one role.

Thanks

Comment: I don't like this approach at all, since you will need a new line in your task list for every new server you add, but also if the server changes its hostname (e.g. you replace it) you could end up without a cron job on that server.

Cron jobs should not be centralized and when you think about it, they aren't. Cron jobs are tied to a specific server function, which makes it natural to define crons in either roles or playbooks that setup a specific server function.

Comment: Are you putting every single cron job at the same place? Consider the size of this playbook and the confusion it can be maintain it.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a couple of ways to skin this cat. The one that comes to mind first is you could assign all servers to one or more roles, and have crons associated to your roles.

Comment: Hi, initially I thought the same idea as you but it seems is not an elegant solution :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think ansible is the right tool for this task. What you want is a job schedule manager and not a configuration manager.

[Chronos](http://airbnb.github.io/chronos/) may be a more suitable tool for the task.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to keep the cron jobs specific to an application with the application code itself in a file named 'crontab.txt'. Its optional, but if it exists, Ansible will copy it into crontab automatically.

```
- name: Check if cron file exists
  stat: path=/path/to/config/cron.txt
  register: cron_file

- name: Copy crontab if exists
  shell: crontab /path/to/config/cron.txt
  when: cron_file.stat.exists is defined and cron_file.stat.exists
```

This will create a new crontab file.

**POTENTIAL ISSUE:** If you have multiple instances of the same application, then depending on the Crontab tasks, which might be interacting with a central database, you run the risk of duplicating tasks (doing the same Cron job x the number of instances of the app you are running). Solutions to this might be to include a check of the hostname/ip so that the task to install the crontab is only run on one instance.